# django no such table: django_session looks at sqlite3 instead of postgres

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

When i run my server with  the runserver command everything works fine.
But when i use nginx, i get this error: "no such table: django_session"
    /home/pi/var/www/venv/evesite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485

I wonder why he suddenly goes to sqlite3 instead of postgres.
I checked my nginx and gunicorn config and they point to the same settingsfile as runserver

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "daf",
        'USER': "sult",
        'PASSWORD': "mypassword",
        'HOST': "localhost",
        'PORT': "",
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: probably you're replacing your db config somewhere… or have routers.

Comment: I got a router but dont think that is the problem. It worked fine before. just wanted to change my database from sqlite to postgress. Migrating and loading with static data all went perfect. its just when i try to access it through my server instead of development server it gets this error. Checked errorlogs but nothing there as well

Comment: Do you split your settings into different files for dev and production? Sounds like you don't use the same django settings.

Comment: nope just one file so far

Comment: Tried removing pyc files?
Could the PATH and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env vars from a different project on the same computer somehow be included into the environment?

Comment: ah that might be it! ill go try this I ported my project to my raspberry pi without deleting those files

Comment: nope did not work. However it seem to be a local problem so maybe still my router. If i access the site with my mobile online it works just fine. thanks for the help